# How in Vue(Quasar) remove the arrows in the carousel in a simple condition

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

Here is is the condition I need:

If there is one picture, just do not show the arrows on the sides; if there is more than one, then show it.

or you can find it in https://quasar.dev/vue-components/carousel

```
<template>
    <div class="q-pa-md">
        <q-carousel
           swipeable
           animated
      arrows
      v-model="slide"
      v-model:fullscreen="fullscreen"
      infinite
    >
      <q-carousel-slide :name="1" img-src="https://cdn.quasar.dev/img/mountains.jpg" />
      <q-carousel-slide :name="2" img-src="https://cdn.quasar.dev/img/parallax1.jpg" />
      <q-carousel-slide :name="3" img-src="https://cdn.quasar.dev/img/parallax2.jpg" />
      <q-carousel-slide :name="4" img-src="https://cdn.quasar.dev/img/quasar.jpg" />

      <template v-slot:control>
        <q-carousel-control
          position="bottom-right"
          :offset="[18, 18]"
        >
          <q-btn
            push round dense color="white" text-color="primary"
            :icon="fullscreen ? 'fullscreen_exit' : 'fullscreen'"
            @click="fullscreen = !fullscreen"
          />
        </q-carousel-control>
      </template>
    </q-carousel>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup () {
    return {
      slide: ref(1),
      fullscreen: ref(false)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: they dont show up. just edited a sample in codepen and they disappear

Comment: I found a solution. I should have made an array of images and write this

:arrows="photos.length > 1"

Here is useful tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kOqMg7n5QVk&ab_channel=LukeDiebold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Make an array of images and write this:

```
:arrows="photos.length > 1"
```